# Achieve PostgreSQL hstore functionality in MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hstore

Please suggest any MySQL 5.5+ Engine that can support collection of key-value pairs be stored in any column of a table.

I don't know if this feature is available out of the box in MySQL like PostgreSQL equivalent to **HSTORE** which is immensely useful and adds some of NoSQL benefits ..

Example in PostgreSQL -

```
SELECT 'a=>1,a=>2'::hstore;
  hstore
----------
 "a"=>"1"
```

source - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

Comment: Somewhat similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2465294/398670

Answer (score 0):

```
-- For MySQL 5.7+
CREATE TABLE your_table_5_7 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSON
);

INSERT INTO your_table_5_7 (id, data)
VALUES (1, '{"a": 1, "b": 2}');

SELECT data->'$.a' AS value_a, data->'$.b' AS value_b
FROM your_table_5_7;
```